# '(', <expression>, <operator>, FETCH, GROUP, HAVING, LIMIT, OFFSET or ORDER expected, got ''7''

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm just starting to work with Postgres and Spring Boot, and I would like to know how to solve a problem I'm facing. Specifically, I'm looking for a query that can help me find digital certificates whose deadline is within seven days or less. However, I keep encountering an error message. Could you please advise me on how to proceed?

```
'(', <expression>, <operator>, FETCH, GROUP, HAVING, LIMIT, OFFSET or ORDER expected, got ''7"
```

That's my code:

```
public interface CertificadoRepository extends JpaRepository<Certificado, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Endereco> {

    //Query para ver os certificados que vencem em 7 dias
    @Query(value = "SELECT c "
        + " FROM Certificate c "
        + " WHERE "
        + " c.dtValidade BETWEEN current_date() AND current_date() + INTERVAL '7' DAY")
    List<Certificado> findCertificadosVencidos();
}
```

[image]

I hope you guys can help me... and fix my code.

Comment: Note that your screenshot shows an error from a third-party IDE plugin. It's much better to actually *run* the query, and tell us about errors reported by Hibernate itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not HQL syntax for duration expression, that is SQL syntax.

The correct HQL in Hibernate 6 is:

```
select c 
from Certificate c
where c.dtValidade between local date and local date + 7 day
```

Please see:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-duration-literals

and:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-datetime-literals
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-Datetime-arithmetic

Comment: Ok, but a still gotting string error.<expression>, <operator>, FETCH, GROUP, HAVING, LIMIT, OFFSET or ORDER expected, got 'day'

@Query(value = "select c"
            + " from Certificate c"
            + " where c.dtValidade between local date and local date + 7 day ")
    List<Certificado> getRunnableParkedQueries(@Param("interval")String interval);

Comment: I think my error is more on String.

Comment: Have you actually tried *running* the code? Or are you just telling me the error that is reported by your IDE plugin? Because I just tried running an essentially identical query on 6.2 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I actually didnt tried to run.